# JavaFx Chart with connected table

Tags: charts, javafx, linechart

I am trying to create a line chart in JavaFx where i have an Y-axis of numbers (integers) and an X-Axis of days.

Now creating the chart was quite simple but i do however have a more complicated problem.

My boss wants me to add the information of each day under each Mark (x-axis) at the correct day. This may sound simple but i have not been able to find a single JavaFx example where the chart and the table are created as one.

So far my program looks like this:

[image]

How can I synchronize the chart and table without wasting hours doing it manually?

**Update - a more precise explanation:**

If you look at my picture the graph and table are divided into two separate components! What I want is a graph and a table in one component.

Let me give an example:

Under the X-axis where it says Man (danish short for Monday) I want to display all the information from Monday in a table with the following information (read from graph)

- Linje 1: 25.
- Linje 2: 78 (about there)
- linje 3: 100

I want those information (and preferably with the color of each line as-well) under each day.

***So to sum up***

I want 1 chart with a table that is connected which means that my table will be removed and instead in graved into the chart so that it is easy to read the precise information from each of the points on the chart.

Comment: Cannot get the relation between "information of each day under each Mark" and "syncronize the chart and table". Can you explain it more?

Comment: sure updating my original post

Comment: Have you seen my update?

Comment: @UlukBiy do you know how to do it?

Comment: look [this image](http://i.imgur.com/3ZsGL.png) and say which one of A or B in the image you are talking about. In both cases it needs a solid work of coding. I think it is hard to implement that  without knowing or using internal protected methods of Chart in general.

Comment: @UlukBiy i prefer the B one but i guess it is the hardest one to code but what you should there is exactly my idea under each day should be a table with the data displayed for that day! (in the example there are only 3 lines but there could be up to 15 lines)

i dont know if it is easier but if you add it like this: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Controls/Table/Table%20Cell%20Factory

Comment: @UlukBiy any news on how i might achive it?